# How to linearize a power function $y=a\cdot x^{b} + c$

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms, linearization

I have this power function:

[image: Power regression]

$$y=a\cdot x^{b} + c$$ and I would like to linearise it into the form: $$y=a\cdot x + b$$
I am trying to linearise it because most algorithms for regression are usually done with linear regression. Colleagues of mine told me that I could perhaps put it into the log space to linearise it and do the same statistics as a linear regression.
So, I have been trying to put it into the log space but I got stuck. There is ton of help online for the equation in the following form:
$$y=a\cdot x^{b} $$
$$log(y) = log(a\cdot x^{b})$$
$$log(y) = b\cdot log(x) + log(a)$$
But I cannot find a way to include the $c$ into this and I need it in my case. So I am stuck here:
$$log(y) = log(a\cdot x^{b} + c)$$
Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What makes you think this is possible to do?

Comment: Is there a reason you think it could be done? You can solve for $x$ easily enough, so exactly why do you want to do this?

Comment: Hello, made a slight edit with a graphic of what I am talking about. I hope it will orientate better the reader. I am not sure it would be possible so I am giving my shot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best you can do is to subtract $c$ from $y$ and treat $y-c$ as the quantity you are considering.

If you are trying to linearize it in order to perform least squares optimization on the data, your problem is that you have $3$ parameters instead of $2$.  You can't convert it to linear because a line has only two parameters.

Comment: In other words, $\log(y-c)=\log a+b\log x$, a linear relation between $\log x$ and $\log(y-c)$.

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer! I think that I am then doomed to do the statistics on the power regression. Thanks anyway!